# LyX: How to define a new number format

Tags: lyx

I am using LyX 2.3. I need to format the numbered list as J-1., J-2., and so on. An example of the output is given below:

[image]

By default, I am getting the list as 1, 2, and so on. Would anyone please suggest how to define a new number format?

Thank you.

**Update**:
Following the solution, I am getting below output.

[image]

Output
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Customisable Lists (enumitem) module (which uses the enumeitem package).

To do so, go to `Document->Settings->Modules` and add the Customisable Lists (enumitem) module to the document.

Now, as usual, start an enumerate layout in lyx, and go to `insert->Enumerate Option` (or just press alt+A 1), and in the inset that now appeared open an ERT layout with `Insert->TeX Code` (or Ctr+L), and write `label=J-\arabic*.` for the first list, or `C-\arabic*.` for the second one.

For more information about the syntax of the enumeitem package you should read it's [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). Here is a lyx file with the wanted output:

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
enumitem
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 1
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\pdf_bookmarks false
\pdf_bookmarksnumbered false
\pdf_bookmarksopen false
\pdf_bookmarksopenlevel 1
\pdf_breaklinks false
\pdf_pdfborder false
\pdf_colorlinks false
\pdf_backref false
\pdf_pdfusetitle false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date true
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\branch blind
\selected 1
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation skip
\defskip smallskip
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\bullet 0 0 2 -1
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Enumerate
\begin_inset Argument 1
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

label=J-
\backslash
arabic*.
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset

Journal 1
\end_layout

\begin_layout Enumerate
Journal 2
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Separator plain
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Enumerate
\begin_inset Argument 1
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

label=C-
\backslash
arabic*.
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset

Paper 1
\end_layout

\begin_layout Enumerate
Paper 2
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Thanks Udi. However, I am not getting the output as expected. I am updating my question attaching the output I am getting with the above solution. Would you please point me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Also, the "documentation" link is not working for me.

Comment: Hi @1118716, I've fixed the broken link and edited the lyx file. It seems that the problem can be fixed with putting the argument in ERT layout. It is probably a bug in the module that i fixed and forgot about, it is discussed in the mailing list here (with my solution):  https://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg114016.html

Comment: Note that you only need to change the module file as discussed in the mailing list, or use ERT, not both.